# Querying a Neo4j DB using Django

Tags: python, django, neo4j

I apologize before hand as the Django way of thinking is still very alien to me. I am trying to generate a very simple page that justs lists all results from a simple cypher query using Neo4j and Django (1.9.7) and I am using the Python Neo4j driver to access the database from Django. However, I am getting stuck and have reached the point where I am just blindly trying things, as such I would like some pointers/advice on how the basics of what I am trying to achieve should look.

models.py

```
from django.views.generic.listimport ListView
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
from django.db import models

# Connect to DB
driver=GraphDatabase.driver("foo1",auth=basic_auth("foo2","foo3"))
session=driver.session()

class Stuff(models.Model):
  query = "MATCH (t:Time) return t"
  results=session.run(query)
  # Sanity check -> This just shows that the database and query both work
  for foo in results:
    print foo
    break
  def __str__(self):
    return results
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Stuff

# I assume that I should be using a ListView here (as I was trying to get a queryset or similar from my models).
class IndexView(ListView):
  template_name = 'index.html'

  def get_queryset(self):
    fooList = []
    for record in Stuff.objects.get():
      fooList.append(record)
    return fooList
```

index.html (not tested as I haven't managed to get this to 'show' yet)

```
{% block body %}

{% if fooList %}
  <h1>Woot!</h1>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

The above bits obviously don't work and complain about `Stuff` not having any `objects`, yet I am totally lost on how to continue (as I have been unable to find any good examples/documentation on using this driver inside Django).

Comment: Are you saying that you are not getting `results` from Neo4j query? Could you please be more specific with the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/session.html) of `session` object in neo4j python driver run method state that

```
run(statement, parameters=None, **kwparameters)
```

it returns `StatementResult` object as documented [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/session.html#neo4j.v1.StatementResult)

So according to the docs there is no `objects` property and therefore `.objects.get()` method does not exists.

Right way to do access records in returned `StatementResult` is shown in [example](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/) as following:

```
for record in result:
      print("%s %s" % (record["title"], record["name"]))
```

So in your case you may want to do:

```
for record in Stuff:
  fooList.append(record)
```

Comment: That is one of the things that I had tried previously, which yields `'ModelBase' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Acording this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512491/typeerror-object-is-not-iterable)

You can't iterate over a model instance. However there is solution if you still require to to it.

Comment: I am still loooking for a way to get this working (being able to query a neo4j database and showing the results using this driver), just be aware that while you are focussing on the `model` that I myself am not 100% sure that using `model` in such a way is even correct when using an existing neo4j database.

Comment: Google suggests following links you may find useful:  
- [neo4j-django-tutorial](https://github.com/johanlundberg/neo4j-django-tutorial) 
- [neo4django](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a flat REsTFul API to communicate with a frontend maybe written in React Angular2 to dump and display your data. So first , you can use DRF(Django rest Framework), then everything would happen mostly in your views.py and serializers.py and a bit in your models.py.  Why avoiding Django template, the query load might affect your app to run smoothly.